# Why can't a user in my group write to this file?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a file on server that can be written by a group.  The group is called "deploy" and the user is "mima."  I have verified "mima" is in "deploy" with:

```
$ id mima
uid=1001(mima) gid=1002(mima) groups=1002(mima),1000(wheel),1001(deploy)
```

The permissions on the file I want to edit are:

```
$ ls -l application_helper.rb 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy 460 2012-08-13 21:30 application_helper.rb
```

This seems like it should work because the group deploy can write and mima is in that group, but I do get a permissions error.

Comment: exclusionary lock by another process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did your user switch to that group with:

```
newgrp deploy
```

?

Comment: Ah that did it.  I was under the impression adding a user to a group was enough so that a user can actively be in multiple groups.  I'll have to read up a bit more on this stuff

Comment: Is there a way to have the user always be in that group?

Comment: @Tony it does work that way, but it doesn't apply retroactively to a user who is logged in while the change is being made to the user/group database. Privileges are decided at login time, granted to the login shell, and inherited from there by all descendant processes, so a user who's been put into a new group has to log in again to use it, or use a privileged (setuid) helper like `newgrp` or `sg` to gain the new gid. This also means if you want to revoke group membership, you have to kill all of the user's processes afterward to cut him off!